# How can I run a method before redirecting?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In a specific view, is it possible to run a method in rails before redirecting to any page? My goal is to change the "ordering" attribute in my task objects according to their ordering in a list before I redirect.

MORE INFO

Below is a picture of my task_manager. Users can drag tasks to different day divs. Before the user redirects to a new page, I would like to call a method in the view that parses each day div and updates the ordering attribute for my task model.

[image]

Comment: Call the method before you redirect-what's the issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can define helper method. Which is a method defined in the controller and can be accessed from the view.

```
def your_method
  ...
end
helper_method :current_user
```

Then in the view you can call it like this:

```
<% your_method %>
```

Comment: But is there a way to call it before a redirect? I don't want to call it initially when the view is rendered

Comment: @derrickmar Call it from the method you redirect in.

Comment: But a variation of methods can be called and are used elsewhere so I cannot do that.

Answer (score 0):

Please provide some more info on what you are trying to do.

Assuming you have a TasksController handling your Task objects, you would have an index action which would render your tasks index view where your tasks are displayed. Before rendering the view you could order the list of tasks.

If you are redirecting however, the @tasks instance variable in your TasksController would not be available to the target page.

Comment: More information posted above. Again, I want to call a method when redirecting not on the initial render.